# Inferred type in for comprehension

Tags: scala, scalaz

Setup:

```
import scalaz._; import Scalaz._

case class Foo(map: Map[Int, String] = Map.empty, set: Set[Int] = Set.empty)

val `foo.map`: Lens[Foo, Map[Int, String]] = Lens.lensu((f, m) => f.copy(map = m), _.map)
val `foo.set`: Lens[Foo, Set[Int]] = Lens.lensu((f, s) => f.copy(set = s), _.set)

case class Bar(cond: Boolean)

val listOfBars = List(Bar(true), Bar(false))
```

Now this doesn't compile

```
listOfBars.runTraverseS[Foo, Unit](Foo()) { bar =>
  if (bar.cond)
    `foo.map` += 1 -> "a"
  else
    `foo.set` += 2
}
```

This issue is that a `Lens[Foo, Map[K, V]].+=` returns a `State[Foo, Map[K, V]]` whereas `Lens[Foo, Set[A]].+=` returns a `State[Foo, Set[A]]`. Recall that `State[S, A]` is invariant in `A`

However, this does compile:

```
listOfBars.runTraverseS[Foo, Unit](Foo()) { bar =>
  for {
    _ <- State.init[Foo]
    x <- {

         if (bar.cond)
           `foo.map` += 1 -> "a"
         else
           `foo.set` += 2

    }
  } yield ()
}
```

1. **Why does this compile?**
2. What is the type of `x`? (IDEA says it's `type $_1` or something like that - I assume that it is not a denotable type)

### EDIT

If I change `yield ()` to `yield println(x)` and println the output of the for comprehension, I get this:

```
Map(1 -> a)
Set(2)
(Foo(Map(1 -> a),Set(2)),List((), ()))
```

Comment: This is wacky. I'm looking at the decompiled code for the second example, reconstructing it in IDEA and it doesn't compile O_o.

Comment: I'm using scalaz **v7.2.7** and scala **v2.12.3**

Comment: Your code snippet compiles fine. When I look at `-Xprint:typer`, it emits invalid Scala which doesn't compile.

Comment: Oh, I see. Another odd thing, if I change `yield ()` for `yield x` it still compiles and I get a warning that *a pure expression does nothing in statement position*

Comment: This is what I see: https://gist.github.com/YuvalItzchakov/e309e138646ffa318be4645e0ac53d08

Comment: I don't see anything in the generated code that turn `Map[Int, String]` into `Unit`. Not sure how that works..

Comment: Not really an answer, but you can see the same thing with e.g. `(if (true) Set.empty[Map[String, Int]] else Set.empty[Set[Int]]).map(_ => ())`. Remove the `.map(...)` and it compiles on 2.11 but not 2.12.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the type of the if expression

```
if (bar.cond)
  `foo.map` += 1 -> "a"
else
  `foo.set` += 2
```

is `State[Foo, Serializable]` or similar (the common base type that scala can unify the `Map` and the `Set` types); but `runTraverseS[Foo, Unit]` expects a `State[Foo, Unit]` (as `Unit` is declared), and those types cannot unify.

The solution is simple, just map over the result and "void" it like this:

```
val unit = ()

listOfBars.runTraverseS[Foo, Unit](Foo()) { bar =>
  (if (bar.cond)
    `foo.map` += 1 -> "a"
  else
    `foo.set` += 2
  ).map(Function.const(unit))
}
```

This is actually what the "for" version of the code does (it just drops the value `x`, whose type is something like `State[Foo, Serializable]`.

Comment: `State[S, A]` is invariant in `A`, so this cannot be the case that scalac would infer a common supertype of `State[_, Serializable]`, which is not to say that you are along the right lines in your analysis. Consider the inferred type of `f` in

 `case class Foo[A](a: A)`
`val f = if (util.Random.nextBoolean()) Foo(1) else Foo("a")`

Comment: Why would invariance disallow for type inference? But otherwise you're right, the inferred type actually is: `scalaz.IndexedStateT[[+X]X, Foo, Foo, _ >: Map[Int,String] with Set[Int] <: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Any] with Int => Any{def seq: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Any] with Int => Any}]`

Comment: Invariance means that it cannot infer the common supertype as you indicated it would do. In my example, `Foo[Any]` is not a common supertype of `Foo[Int]` and `Foo[String]` because `Foo` is invariant in its type parameter.

Comment: Let's try it out in a scala console:
`case class Invariant[A](a1: A, a2: A)`
`Invariant(1, "string")`
What did you get? Did inferring the common supertype happen?